# python with selenium: element invisible when getting multiple elements

Tags: python, selenium

I want to realize a simple function for a web game: automatically detect enemy and attack them.

```
content = browser.page_source
if re.search(r'\[NewEnemy\]', content): # enemy detected
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='list']").click() # access enemy list
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='enemy']").click()    # attack
        go back
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

This works fine even without WebDriverWait. But sometimes there might be multiple targets, so I modified the code to

```
content = browser.page_source
if re.search(r'\[NewEnemy\]', content): # enemy detected
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='list']").click() # access enemy list
    try:
        for battle in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href*='enemy']"):    # attack one by one
            battle.click()
            go back
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

However, I kept on getting element invisible exceptions. Actually in most cases there is only 1 target but it never worked. I really don't get it. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the `go back`? Does it actually run?

Comment: @Or It's pseudo code, which basically reloads the frame.  I'm sure it works fine

Comment: `go back SyntaxError: invalid syntax` what version of python do you use? is that CPython? I never saw this syntax

Comment: @OrDuan I'm sorry but "go back" is actually pseudo code here. The real code is a little complicated in my case, I don't feel necessary to put them here. I'm using python 3.5.2.